# How to restore python lambda without any deletion of CloudFormation Stack

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

By mistake I deleted python lambda which is using for **CDKBucketDeployment**. I'm facing this issue while deploy my new changes. I don't want to delete my existing **CloudFormation Stack** because if I delete this I need to create new Cognito User Pool and my application url will also change. Please find error below :

```
devWebClientStack: deploying...

[0%] start: Publishing c9ac4b3b65f3510a2088b7fd003de23d2aefac424025eb168725ce6769e3c176:current

[50%] success: Published c9ac4b3b65f3510a2088b7fd003de23d2aefac424025eb168725ce6769e3c176:current

[50%] start: Publishing f50bf04d69a5f8fec61ba6b259e3f76a66edc48a22f6b802dcc80d5bb807ed95:current

[100%] success: Published f50bf04d69a5f8fec61ba6b259e3f76a66edc48a22f6b802dcc80d5bb807ed95:current

devWebClientStack: creating CloudFormation changeset...

0/2 | 5:25:47 PM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | devWebClientStack User Initiated

0/2 | 5:25:54 PM | UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS | Custom::CDKBucketDeployment | DeployWithInvalidation/CustomResource/Default (DeployWithInvalidationCustomResourceE3FF7455)

0/2 | 5:25:55 PM | UPDATE_FAILED | Custom::CDKBucketDeployment | DeployWithInvalidation/CustomResource/Default (DeployWithInvalidationCustomResourceE3FF7455) Function not found: arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:316993037060:function:devWebClientStack-CustomCDKBucketDeployment8693BB6-OJIUwTSmAVQV (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 404; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: 77adec99-0a74-4127-9c7c-086fc14a3051; Proxy: null)

new CustomResource (C:\qa\vcop\deployments\web-client\node_modules\@aws-cdk\core\lib\custom-resource.ts:115:21)

\_ new BucketDeployment (C:\qa\vcop\deployments\web-client\node_modules\@aws-cdk\aws-s3-deployment\lib\bucket-deployment.ts:201:5)

\_ new WebClientStack (C:\qa\vcop\deployments\web-client\lib\web-client-stack.ts:54:5)

\_ Object.<anonymous> (C:\qa\vcop\deployments\web-client\bin\web-client.ts:7:1)

\_ Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)

\_ Module.m._compile (C:\qa\vcop\deployments\web-client\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1043:23)

\_ Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)

\_ Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\qa\vcop\deployments\web-client\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1046:12)

\_ Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)

\_ Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)

\_ Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)

\_ main (C:\qa\vcop\deployments\web-client\node_modules\ts-node\src\bin.ts:225:14)

\_ Object.<anonymous> (C:\qa\vcop\deployments\web-client\node_modules\ts-node\src\bin.ts:512:3)

\_ Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)

\_ Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)

\_ Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)

\_ Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)

\_ Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)

\_ internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

0/2 | 5:25:56 PM | UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_P | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | devWebClientStack The following resource(s) failed to update: [DeployWithInvalidationCustomResourceE3FF7455].

2/2 | 5:26:04 PM | UPDATE_COMPLETE | Custom::CDKBucketDeployment | DeployWithInvalidation/CustomResource/Default (DeployWithInvalidationCustomResourceE3FF7455)

2/2 | 5:26:05 PM | UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMP | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | devWebClientStack

2/2 | 5:26:05 PM | UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMP | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | devWebClientStack

❌ devWebClientStack failed: Error: The stack named devWebClientStack failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLL

BACK_COMPLETE

at Object.waitForStackDeploy (C:\qa\vcop\deployments\web-client\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\api\util\cloudformation.ts:307:11)

at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

at Object.deployStack (C:\qa\vcop\deployments\web-client\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\api\deploy-stack.ts:283:26)

at CdkToolkit.deploy (C:\qa\vcop\deployments\web-client\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\cdk-toolkit.ts:180:24)

at initCommandLine (C:\qa\vcop\deployments\web-client\node_modules\aws-cdk\bin\cdk.ts:201:9)

The stack named devWebClientStack failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! web-client@0.1.0 deploy: `cdk deploy --require-approval never`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the web-client@0.1.0 deploy script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR! C:\Users\CYAQT\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-10T11_56_08_461Z-debug.log
```

Kindly please suggest any solution. how can I restore lambda without any loss?

Answer (score 0):

I would contact AWS Support, they might be able to talk you through how to correct this manually.